# ¿Cómo agregar un List<Button> en un panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de agregar una lista de botones que fue creada dinámicamente dentro de un panel, no marca ningún error, pero no muestra nada, por lo que hay algún error

Este es mi código:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposFCHOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposFCHOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.Text = team;
                Botones.Add(newButton);
            }

            Botones = Panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
        }
```

y este es mi panel:

```
    <div id="tgood">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_eng" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: Yo no termino de ver donde añades los botones al panel. No seria mejor poner en tu bucle `foreach` algo como `Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);`?

Comment: ooh asi que era newButton... yo intentaba agregar la lista como tal `GoodPanel.Controls.Add(Botones);`

Comment: Mira mi respuesta para añadir una coleccion

Comment: suena muy interesante, lo ponder en practica :) muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar los controles de uno en uno, seria mejor poner en tu bucle foreach algo como `Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);`.
Si lo que quieres es agregar una colección de controles, puedes probar con [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Panel1.Controls.AddRange(Botones.ToArray());
```